# Can I detect voltage or ampere from my computer on an circuit

Tags: drivers, usb

Can I make some software using c++/c so that I can detect the voltage or ampere used by my circuit.

- Simply I wanted to know can my linux on x86amd detect some external circuit and measure and tell my program the amphere , voltage,or signals received.
- **example**:-  like making a bare carbon microphone and attach it to usb wire and connecting to computer and testing some amount signals got received or not.if received can I interpret it.
- Does makeing some computer drivers let me do so.

Comment: your usual desktop computer or laptop probably won't have interfaces like that, and for USB, you need to talk the USB protocol, it's not just random voltages on a wire. (a computer could have sensors used for fixed function, e.g. voltage and temperature sensors for a laptop battery and such) Look into embedded-like hardware, like Raspberry Pi's and Arduinos.

Comment: @ilkkachu  you just meant that I cannot means voltage and current directly I must need some sensors but can you just talk about my microphone example above will that works how can I receive it's signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I make some software using c++/c so that I can detect the voltage or ampere used by my circuit.

You can make your own circuit and connect it up the line-in or mic-in input; this will give you a voltage measurement in a certain range up to whatever sample rate your audio hardware supports. With a suitable circuit you can measure other voltages or current.

> like making a bare carbon microphone and attach it to usb wire

You cannot use USB for anything other than a USB protocol. You can't even measure digital values from USB pins.

However, you can buy a sensor chip with a USB interface, then you can measure whatever the sensor chip will let you measure.